# Sublime Text autostart a file

Tags: macos, sublimetext3

I am looking for a way to tell Sublime Text to open a specific file on startup.
Is that possible?
I know that Sublime always opens the last opened file when the attribute `hot_exit` is set to true.
However, I would like a certain file that is on my desktop to always be opened when sublime is opened.

Regards Anibas

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using MacOS.

Comment: You can pass sublime_text.exe [file_name]:[line_number] or sublime_text.exe [file_name] in windows. Maybye this will help.